# How to make Modbus TCP Server using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, modbus-tcp

Currently I want to create some project using Modbus TCP server using visual Studio 2022. But I don't know how to start it. Is there a good website or resource where I can learn about it?

I've opened it on the internet. but haven't found the right site yet.